# page.hover() having no effect

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, deno, deno-puppeteer

### Description

Some buttons on my website change color on hover, however when using [deno-puppeteer](/questions/tagged/deno-puppeteer) it would appear to be having no effect.

### Relevant code:

```js
import { puppeteer } from './deps.ts';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

const url = 'https://sweet-snake-49.deno.dev';
await page.goto(url);
await page.setViewport({
    width: 1600,
    height: 1200
});
await page.hover('#left');
await page.screenshot({ path: Deno.cwd() + '/example.png' }); 

await browser.close();
```

Complete project to reproduce [here](https://github.com/kemicofa/deno-puppeteer-hover-example).

### Expected output

On hover, I expect the color to change to a yellow with box-shadow, but unfortunately it's as if no hover is being attributed to my button.

**From:**

[image]

**To:**

[image]

### Question

How can I get `page.hover()` to work on my `#left` button ?

*It would not appear to be related to deno as the exact same issue is happening with nodejs*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a Docker container (because I'm not comfortable with essentially disabling the security sandbox by using the liberal permissions required by deno-puppeteer), so my config is a bit different from yours.

I have modified both the [Dockerfile template from the `deno-puppeteer` repo](https://github.com/lucacasonato/deno-puppeteer/blob/9.0.2/Dockerfile), and your source file, and I get a successful hover state in the screenshot:

> Note that the target page you linked to uses the glyph `◀` ([U+25C0 BLACK LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE](https://codepoints.net/U+25C0?lang=en)) for the text inside the left button — and, it doesn't appear to render in the container: the screenshot shows a default box character in place of it. I suppose a compatible font would need to be installed as an additional step in the Dockerfile in order to address this: more debugging would be required.

[image: Controls with left button hovered]

In order to keep the code available on Stack Overflow (rather than relying on external hosting), I'll inline the contents of the files in my reproduction directory (I've named it `so-70731163` after the ID of your question), along with the console input/output:

---

`./.vscode/settings.json`

```json
{
  "deno.enable": true,
  "deno.lint": true,
  "deno.unstable": true,
  "deno.config": "./src/deno.json"
}
```

`./src/deno.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "deno.window",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ]
  }
}
```

`./src/deps.ts`

```ts
export * as path from 'https://deno.land/std@0.122.0/path/mod.ts';
export {
  assert,
  assertExists,
} from 'https://deno.land/std@0.122.0/testing/asserts.ts';
export {
  default as puppeteer,
  type ElementHandle,
  type ScreenshotOptions,
} from 'https://deno.land/x/puppeteer@9.0.2/mod.ts';
```

`./src/main.ts`

```ts
import {
  assert,
  assertExists,
  path,
  puppeteer,
  type ElementHandle,
  type ScreenshotOptions,
} from './deps.ts';

// Create data directory if it doesn't already exist
const dataDir = path.resolve('container-data');
await Deno.mkdir(dataDir, {recursive: true});

// Browser launch options required for usage in Docker
// https://github.com/lucacasonato/deno-puppeteer/issues/16#issuecomment-842784232
// https://github.com/lucacasonato/deno-puppeteer/blob/9.0.2/examples/docker.js
const dockerLaunchArgs = [
  '--no-sandbox',
  '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
];

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: dockerLaunchArgs});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setViewport({width: 1600, height: 1200});

const url = 'https://sweet-snake-49.deno.dev';
await page.goto(url);

// Get handle for left button (used in next step) and hover it
const leftBtnHandle = await page.$('button#left');
assertExists(leftBtnHandle);
await leftBtnHandle.hover();

// Get handle for controls container (for screenshot in next step)
const getControls = (leftBtn: HTMLButtonElement) => leftBtn.closest('section');
const controlsHandle =
  (await leftBtnHandle.evaluateHandle<ElementHandle>(getControls)).asElement();
assertExists(controlsHandle);

// Instead of using Puppeteer API to save screenshot,
// get raw buffer data for more control
const screenshotOpts: ScreenshotOptions = {encoding: 'binary', type: 'png'};
const pngData = await controlsHandle.screenshot(screenshotOpts);
assert(pngData instanceof Uint8Array);
const screenshotPath = path.join(dataDir, 'controls.png');
await Deno.writeFile(screenshotPath, pngData);

await browser.close();
```

`./docker-build`

```sh
docker build --tag so-70731163 .
```

`./docker-run`

```sh
docker run -it \
  --rm \
  --name so-70731163 \
  --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",destination=/app \
  so-70731163
```

`./Dockerfile`

```
FROM debian:buster-slim

ENV DENO_VERSION=1.18.0
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get -qq update \
    && apt-get -qq install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    unzip \
# ↓ https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix
# Since I want to leave the contents of troubleshooting.md as it is, ca-certificates is intentionally duplicated here.
    ca-certificates \
    fonts-liberation \
    libappindicator3-1 \
    libasound2 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libc6 \
    libcairo2 \
    libcups2 \
    libdbus-1-3 \
    libexpat1 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libgbm1 \
    libgcc1 \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libpango-1.0-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    libstdc++6 \
    libx11-6 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxext6 \
    libxfixes3 \
    libxi6 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libxrender1 \
    libxss1 \
    libxtst6 \
    lsb-release \
    wget \
    xdg-utils \
# ↑ https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix
# ↓ Added based on the information obtained from by console.log(line) at https://deno.land/x/puppeteer@9.0.2/src/deno/BrowserRunner.ts#L168.
    libdrm2 \
    libxkbcommon0 \
    libxshmfence1 \
# ↑ Added based on the information obtained from by console.log(line) at https://deno.land/x/puppeteer@9.0.2/src/deno/BrowserRunner.ts#L168.
    && curl -fsSL https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/download/v${DENO_VERSION}/deno-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.zip \
    --output deno.zip \
    && unzip deno.zip \
    && rm deno.zip \
    && chmod 755 deno \
    && mv deno /usr/bin/deno \
    && apt-get -qq remove --purge -y \
    curl \
# Do not remove ca-certificates as it is required by puppeteer.
#    ca-certificates \
    unzip \
    && apt-get -y -qq autoremove \
    && apt-get -qq clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN useradd --uid 1993 --user-group deno \
 && mkdir /deno-dir/ \
 && chown deno:deno /deno-dir/

ENV DENO_DIR /deno-dir/

# --- PLACE CUSTOM COMMANDS BELOW --- #

WORKDIR /app
# Bind CWD instead of copying
# COPY . .

# https://deno.land/x/puppeteer@9.0.2#installation
# In your real script, replace the installation script with https://deno.land/x/puppeteer@9.0.2/install.ts
RUN PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=chrome deno run -A --unstable https://deno.land/x/puppeteer@9.0.2/install.ts

ENTRYPOINT ["deno"]
CMD ["run", "-A", "--no-check", "--unstable", "./src/main.ts"]
```

---

In the console:

```
so-70731163 % ./docker-build
# Lots of Docker build output messages...

so-70731163 % ./docker-run
# Lines showing compilation info: Download moduleURL...
```

and afterward, the screenshot from above is written to `./container-data/controls.png`.

To remove the built docker image:

```
docker image rm so-70731163
```

Comment: Thanks, I was unfortunately not available to review the answer in detail by the time the bounty ended. I'll be rewarding this one.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the element to exist, then try to interact with the element once found in the DOM.

Example using Puppeteer's page waitForSelector:

```
import { puppeteer } from './deps.ts';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

const url = 'https://sweet-snake-49.deno.dev';

await page.goto(url);
await page.setViewport({
    width: 1600,
    height: 1200
});

// wait for element before trying to hover
page.waitForSelector('#left').then(() =>
    await page.hover('#left');
    await page.screenshot({ path: Deno.cwd() + '/example.png' }); 
);

await browser.close();
```

Comment: The browser will be closed before the hover.
So Please use await instead of then.